# With out the axiom of choice is the following true: If a topology on $X$ contains every infinite subset of $X$, then this is the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology

Is there a way to prove the following without having to use the axiom of choice or its countable version?

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $T$ be a topology on $X$. If $T$ contains every infinite subset of $X$, then $T$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: The answer is no and this is a possible duplicate of these question and answer [here1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60269/question-regarding-subsets-of-infinite-sets) (especially the answer), [here2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233350/is-the-discrete-topology-on-x-the-only-one-containing-all-infinite-subsets-of?rq=1), . If this does not answer your question you should edit yours to make it more apparent that it doesn't answer the question.