# indiscrete topology

Tags: general-topology

Let X be an infinite set and let $\mathcal T $ be a topology on X.

2) prove that if $\mathcal T $ contains every infinite subset of X, then it is the indiscrete topology.

i think this is untrue, consider $X= \Bbb N $ the indiscrete topology has two sets $\{\emptyset ,\Bbb N\}$  but we have for example $2\Bbb N $ and $\Bbb P $ which are not in the indiscrete topology?

Comment: while indiscreet is a real word, the correct word here is indiscrete   http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051773/

Comment: spellchecks a ***** but it has nothing to do with math, i had it spelt right it just flagged it.

Comment: The correct conclusion we can actually draw is that $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology, for which see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60269/if-a-topology-contains-all-infinite-subsets-then-it-is-the-discrete-topology?rq=1).

Comment: thats must be the intended question, thank you i was sure this didnt work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every infinite subset of $X$ is declared open, then this topology is the *discrete* topology, not the indiscrete one.

To see this, take an arbitrary *countably* infinite subset $Y$ of $X$. Enumerate the elements of $Y$ as $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots\}$ in such a way that all these elements are distinct (that is, $y_n\neq y_m$ whenever $n,m\in\mathbb N$ and $n\neq m$). Now define
\begin{align*}
Y_{\text{o}}\equiv&\;\{y_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\text{ is odd}\}=\{y_1,y_3,y_5,\ldots\},\\
Y_{\text{e}}\equiv&\;\{y_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\text{ is even}\}=\{y_2,y_4,y_6,\ldots\}.
\end{align*}
Then $Y_{\text{o}}$ and $Y_{\text{e}}$ are both infinite and they are disjoint.

Take any arbitrary $x\in X$. Then, the sets $Y_{\text{o}}\cup\{x\}$ and $Y_{\text{e}}\cup\{x\}$ are both infinite and thus open, and the only common element in them is $x$. The intersection of these two sets, which is $\{x\}$, is therefore open.

It follows that every singleton is an open set, so that the topology must be the discrete one.

Comment: I mean i would of taken a simple yes the question is incorrect but proving its discrete is enough to shows its not indiscrete so i will give it to you.

Comment: @Faust Actually, the discrete and the indiscrete topology are one and the same if $X$ consists of only one element. Thank you for the accept! :-)