Question about discrete topology and the use of union and intersection to obtain singleton.
I currently reading Topology without tears by Sidney A. Morris and I encountered a question about discrete topology:

Let $X$ be an infinite space and $T$ a topology on $X$. If every infinite subset of $X$ is in $T$, prove that $T$ is the discrete topology.

Clearly we have to show that every singleton is in $T$ but I am unable to figure out how to apply operation such as union of intersection to obtain singleton $\{x\}$ where $x\in X$. Can anyone give me a hint or solve this directly? Thanks for the response!

Related but not quite identical because that question focuses on how to get the infinite-coinfinite subset:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60269/53537

Let $x \in X$ and pick distinct points $x_1,x_2,...$ all distinct from $x$. Then $\{x,x_1,x_3,...\}$ and $\{x,x_2,x_4,...\}$ are both open and so is their intersection $\{x\}$.

Thank you, this is clever!

+1: Note the hidden assumption that $X$ is Dedekind-infinite. This result seems to require at least that much Choice.
